# autorestart service

Tags: linux, debian, redhat, service

I'm looking for a way to auto-restart a service when it crashes (Apache, Proftpd, Jboss...). I'm running debian. I could script something but I'm trying to find a "good practice" for this.

Do you know a software that can do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DJB's Daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) can do exactly what you want.

However, it would be more productive in the long run if you could figure out why things are dying and fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: +1 Been using daemontools for years and can't complain. The only downside is that sometimes junior SAs have trouble grokking what DTs are about.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm one of those who don't grok it, but I know it has a good reputation amongst those who do.

Answer (score 6):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is a relatively easy to configure service that will restart services (and more).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

You can add it to /etc/inittab with the **respawn** action, however, this is usually reserved for lower level system processes that the server itself depends on for basic functionality.

A better option would be to monitor your servers and processes using an external program such as **nagios**, and configuring an **eventhandler** to restart the services if they go down.

Answer (score -8):

Control panels can do this for you as well. For example, here is Webmin http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SystemAndServerStatus